# python os.system block backward command

Tags: python, linux, os.system

I set a timer to monitor these code.

```
def SwitchToDstSystem(SystemNo):
    grub_util.SwitchToSystem(SystemNo = SystemNo)
    logger.debug("switch to %s"%SystemNo)
    time.sleep(10)
    os.system('/usr/bin/setsid /sbin/shutdown -r now &')
    logger.debug("Reboot in 10 seconds")
    time.sleep(10)
def UpgradeGsp(StatusDict):
    SwitchToDstSystem(SystemNo)
while True:
    UpgradeGsp(SystemNo)
```

Sometimes it finish quickly, but sometimes it will timeout. 
I think sometimes `os.system` should be blocked.

My server runs mysql, anyone know why `os.system` is blocked?

```
os.system('/usr/bin/setsid /sbin/shutdown -r now &')
```

Comment: Where is _these code_?

Comment: os.system('/usr/bin/setsid /sbin/shutdown -r now &')

Comment: Please elaborate the question

Comment: I want to reboot the server with os.system('/usr/bin/setsid /sbin/shutdown -r now &') in python script, I print some logs before and after the function. Sometimes the command will executed successfully. But sometimes it will be blocked in os.system function, it won't return and the system won't be rebooted.

Comment: Please reorganize your question to be readable!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't messed with running programs from code lately. But just use `subprocess.call()`
You also need root privileges to use shutdown I think.

```
# Code not tested. If this doesn't work try the `pexpect` module
# to expect the password prompt.
import subprocess
subprocess.call('sudo shutdown -r now')
```

I could write out the full working code but that would take some time. And I think you should finish you problems, it's always fun to complete a challenge.

I only really use subprocess to make program calls or system information.

Pexpect was made to communicate with programs from the command line.
Although you need to add the expectations your self.

[Pexpect API Documentation](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/index.html) : The `Spawn()` class is like `subprocess.call()`. Read [Spawn() Class Docs](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pexpect.html#spawn-class).

(OFF TOPIC: There is a `pxssh` module built from `pexpect`. A very good tool for creating small admin scripts.

Comment: I agree with you! I may change my function later. But now I need explain the reason to the customer. I need to know why.

Comment: Sorry can't help you out there. Say 'it's too technical'. I think changing the function would help your code. If it doesn't help wrap your code in `try: ... except Exception, e: print e` to narrow down your problem, then go from there.

Comment: If you need to. Open up the module your using, in your codes case `os`, and place some `try: except:`'s on the functions your using. This is a lot of work obliviously. But it could be very beneficial. If you can, when you get it to work. I would like to know your solution